# how to stop a script when "warning" appears "Item with specified name already exists?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

My script creates a folder which i define as a variable in the beginning.

like this :

```
$version = "1.65"

$destpath = "C:\something\someprogramm\$version"

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$destPath"
```

when i now create the folder 1.65  my script fills this folder up with all the files i wanted to copy there.

When i run the script a second time he will overwrite the content in this folder.

I want to prevent this accidently overriting, but how is that done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Test-Path` to check if the file or a folder already exists or not.  If exits then do not create it.

```
$destpath = "C:\something\someprogramm\$version"
if(Test-Path $destpath)
{ 
  Write-host "$destpath already exists"
}
else{
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$destPath"
}
```

Comment: But, remember, there will be a time interval between performing the check and creating the file or folder. While this interval is small, that is plenty of time for something else to create it. In practice without a low level "ExistsOrCreate" this will always be a problem.